# Checking pre-exist record in mysql database in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am checking a country name already exist  in my database i used callback but it doest not shoot any error

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('country_name', 'Country Name', 
       'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_exist');
```

This is my controller function

```
function check_exist($country_name)
    {
         $this->countrymodel->country_exists($country_name);

    }
```

and this is my model

```
function country_exists($key)
        {
            $this->db->where('country_name',$key);
            $this->db->from($this->dbname);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            if ($query->num_rows()> 0){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback function should return a value and set a message:

```
function check_exist($country_name)
{
     if (!$this->countrymodel->country_exists($country_name)) {
         $this->form_validation->set_message('check_exist', 'an error message');
         return FALSE;
     }
     else {
         return TRUE;
     }
}
```

Comment: but this is  not working now i can add same country more than 1 times

Comment: Does the model function act as expected?

Comment: You need to be sure. The validation code is correct, as you can see in the manual: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks

Comment: i got it how can i give a custom msg i am getting "Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name."